Convert String to Array[Int] in a Hive column using Spark or Hive
I have sample data as in below string format in Hive table:
+----------------------+

|           col1       |

+----------------------+

|         160-80-40 sec|

|         160-80-40 sec|

| 10-10-10-20-20-30 min|

| 10-10-10-20-20-30 min|

| 10-20-30-40-50-60 min|

|       200-100-100 sec|

|               400 200|

+----------------------+

I need to find the sum of array, max value, min value
when I load this hive table in spark, it will infer the datatype to string
val df = spark.sql("select col1 from table1")
I tried to use split and size in spark dataframe,
first, I split int and string using split function
then again used split with "-" and calculate the sum of array
As it is string type, got error
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'sum(split(`new_col1, '-'))' due to data type mismatch: function sum requires numeric types, not array;;
val df1 = df.withColumn("new_col1", split('col1, " ")(0)) 

df1.withColumn("new_col2", sum(split('new_col1, "-"))) 

is there a way to cast array[string] to array[int] in dataframe
I would like to solve this problem without using UDFs

For spark >= 3.x
You can use higher order function - aggregate as shown below.
  spark.sql("select '1-2-3' as test_col") // sample data
    .select(aggregate(split($"test_col", "-").cast("array<int>"), lit(0), (x,y)=> x+y).as("array_sum"))

For spark < 3.x
  spark.sql("select '1-2-3' as test_col")
    .select(expr("""aggregate(cast(split(test_col, "-") as array<int>), 0, (x,y)-> x+y)""").as("array_sum"))


aggregate is not working for me in spark-shell,  thanks for cast("array") usage before I was applying cast wrong

use import import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ which version  of spark you are using?

Have used import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ and import spark.implicits._ and it didnt work, I am using spark 2.4 and I get error: not found: value aggregate

Updated answers for spark 2.4

I am using UDF's to find min and max of the String, Is there any simple way (using higher order functions)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_max https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_min
